# "Цингами" — ударение (тв. п. мн. ч. от слова "цинга")

Tags: орфоэпия, падежи

Викисловарь [говорит](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0), что правильное ударение *цингАми.* Но почему-то хочется сказать *цИнгами* по аналогии, например, с *зимами.* Или всё-таки Викисловарь прав?

Многих может удивить, когда вообще можно употребить это слово так. Но можно ведь сказать: "Да хрен бы с ними, со всеми этими цингами". Пускай это и не очень литературно.

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за ответы!!!

Answer (score 4):

> *“Цингами”* — ударение (тв. п. мн. ч. от слова *“цинга”*)

Правильного ударения (в обычном понимании) в формах множественного  числа слова *цинга* не существует. Так же, как и в в формах множественного числа слова *борьба*. Просто потому, что способ образования этих форм не определяется однозначно общими правилами русского склонения. Формы эти практически почти никогда не употребляются, и в словарях приводятся лишь в качестве потенциальных форм.

Артём Луговой:

> Викисловарь говорит, что правильное ударение *цингАми*.

Такое ударение приведено и в *"Грамматическом словаре русского языка"* Зализняка. Но Зализняк при этом пишет:

> …Например, неочевидно, как будет построено носителями литературного
>   русского языка (при окказиональном употреблении) мн. число от слова
>   борьба́: борьбы́ (ср., например, мольба́ — мольбы́) или бо́рьбы (ср.,
>   например, стрельба́ — стре́льбы). Словарь даёт в этих случаях индекс,
>   отражающий **наиболее вероятный (с точки зрения составителя)** вариант
>   образования потенциальной формы (или форм), но слово сопровождается
>   указанием о том,  что сведения о соответствующей форме или группе форм
>   носят предположительный характер.

Comment: Так викисловарь и создан по Зализняку. Почти один в один. Если только при переносе где-то ошиблись. Ну а если по сути, так "мнение составителя" - оно ж не на голом месте появилось. Я, например, вижу некоторую логику уже в том, что слово, не до конца пока обкатанное русским языком, не испытывает смещения ударения в падежах. Зализняк тут обычно не ошибается.

Answer (score 2):

[**Толковый словарь иностранных слов** (Л. П. Крысина.- М: Русский язык, 1998)](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/53797/%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0)  утверждает, что множественного числа у "цинги" нет:
**цинга**
и, ***мн. нет***, ж. (< польск. *dzięgna* < лат. *dēns* зуб).
Болезнь, вызываемая недостатком в организме витаминов и проявляющаяся в рыхлости и кровоточивости десен, в мышечно-сосудистых болях, слабости; то же, что скорбут. 
Цинготный — относящийся к цинге.

То же самое утверждается и в [**Энциклопедическом словарике**](https://slovar.cc/enc/slovarik/1814115.html) :
ЦИНГА
и, ***мн. нет*,** ж.

Однако, есть [**формы слов**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_forms/80365/%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0) :
цинга́, цинги́,
цинги́, ци́нг,
цинге́, цинга́м,
цингу́, цинги́,
цинго́й, цинго́ю, **цинга́ми**,
цинге́, цинга́х.
(Источник: «Полная акцентуированная парадигма по А. А. Зализняку»)

Если мы предполагаем/считаем, что множественное число у слова "цинга" всё-таки есть, то форма творительного падежа — ***цинга́ми***.

[Дело в том, что цинга (собственно, как болезнь) единственна в своём "медицинском" роде. У неё нет зафиксированных разновидностей или "особых" форм (например, таких, которые зависят от сезонных, географических или расовых особенностей): она или есть, или ее нет.
Поэтому, думаю, правильно употреблять слово *цинга* только в единственном числе:
*Да и шут с ней, со всей этой цингой*.]

Answer (score 0):

Я бы скорее взял за образец слово *рука - рукАми* или *черта - чертАми.*

Викисловарь исповедует принцип Залиняка (большинство форм у него и взяты), по которому любая форма, которую в принципе возможно образовать, не нарушая каких-то правил, там приводится. Среди них попадаются и совершенно ненормативные (близкие к эрративам) и, так сказать, условно-нормативные (окказионализмы).

Множественное число слова "цинга" как раз к таким и относится. Само понятие, семантика допускает образование множественного числа (чем цинга хуже коклюша или, скажем, склероза?), внешний облик слова и фонетика тому тоже не препятствует.

Поэтому Викисловарь и приводит формы для множественного числа. Однако ж несвободность и неупотребительность этих форм не позволяют объективно разбирать их правильность на уровне отдельных элементов (ударения в частности).

Вместе с тем, есть довольно прочная закономерность, что слова, менее освоенные языком, реже употребляемые, обычно не испытывают смешения ударения при формообразовании.
Так что я все же за ***цингАми***. Минус тут разве только тот, что похоже на "оригами" или "Мураками".

Comment: *Я бы скорее взял за образец слово рука - рукАми или черта - чертАми.* А мне кажется, что *серьга* будет ближе из-за Г. А с ней как раз получается *серьгами.* Но насчёт меньшей освоенности согласен и тому, что в таких словах обычно не меняют ударений, охотно верю.